# Rearrange column hierarchy or change sort order via pivot

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I can use

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
{
   "Day": np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], dtype="int32"),
    "Subject": np.array(['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c']),
     "Breakfast": np.random.randn(9),
     "Lunch": np.random.randn(9),
      "Dinner": np.random.randn(9),  
}
```

)
df2

then

```
df2.pivot(index="Day", columns="Subject")
```

to generate:

[image: Pivot Results]

and want to reorder or change the column hierarchy so that the data details by day and subject are ordered together underneath the subject as per the following:

[image: Desired Pivot Results]

How does one rearrange either the column hierarchy or the column sort order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) along `axis=1` after pivoting the dataframe:

```
df2.pivot(index="Day", columns="Subject").swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(1)
```

Alternatively you can use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) followed by [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to perform reshaping:

```
df2.set_index(['Day', 'Subject']).stack().unstack([1, 2])
```

---

```
Subject         a                             b                             c                    
        Breakfast     Lunch    Dinner Breakfast     Lunch    Dinner Breakfast     Lunch    Dinner
Day                                                                                              
1       -0.558349 -1.386076  1.518792  0.089063 -0.508046  1.095008 -0.260515 -0.087735  1.472237
2        0.876124 -0.574031 -1.089488 -1.439771  0.708469 -0.332422 -0.148037  1.285213 -1.313784
3        0.823619  0.714185  0.726317 -0.385264 -1.031764  0.924519  0.139066  0.296062  1.351840
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
df3 = df2.pivot(index="Day", columns="Subject")
df3.columns = df3.columns.swaplevel()
df3.sort_index(axis=1, level=0, sort_remaining=False, inplace=True)
```

The result (for my random data) is:

```
Subject         a                             b                             c  
        Breakfast     Lunch    Dinner Breakfast     Lunch    Dinner Breakfast      Lunch    Dinner
Day                                                                                               
1       -2.199182  0.810676  1.119673  1.685167 -1.469196  0.838108 -0.751882   1.678362 -0.312479
2       -0.275628  1.224855  1.142574  0.699516 -0.898156 -1.796295  0.593565   0.606979  0.549299
3        0.043365  0.562309  0.881739  0.746961  0.002600  0.344138  0.937465   1.402463  2.065739
```